# strange core dump using unordered map

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, unordered-map, coredump

Here is my code and the problem I am working on with the code, and wondering why there is core dump in my case?

**Question,**

You are playing the following Nim Game with your friend: There is a heap of stones on the table, each time one of you take turns to remove 1 to 3 stones. The one who removes the last stone will be the winner. You will take the first turn to remove the stones.

Both of you are very clever and have optimal strategies for the game. Write a function to determine whether you can win the game given the number of stones in the heap.

For example, if there are 4 stones in the heap, then you will never win the game: no matter 1, 2, or 3 stones you remove, the last stone will always be removed by your friend.

**Code,**

```
#include <iostream>
class Solution {
public:
    bool canWinNim(int n) {
        std::unordered_map<int, bool> cache;
        return canWinNimHelper(n, cache);
    }
    
    bool canWinNimHelper(int n, std::unordered_map<int, bool>& cache) {
        if (n <= 3) {
            return true;   
        }
        auto iter = cache.find(n);
        if (iter != cache.end()) {
            return iter->second;
        }
        if ((!canWinNimHelper(n-1, cache)) || (!canWinNimHelper(n-2, cache)) || (!canWinNimHelper(n-3, cache))) {
            cache[n] = true;
            return true;
        }
        
        cache[n] = false;
        return false;        
    }
};

int main() {
    Solution s;
    s.canWinNim(1348820612);
}
```

Comment: BTW, it seems the core dump is very specific to this input, 1348820612, I tried other values, like 42, there is no issues.

Comment: Recursion depth too great?

Comment: @NeilButterworth, I also has the same guess, and how to prove? And why recursive too high reports as seg fault?

Comment: @NeilButterworth, is there any functional bugs in my code which may cause seg fault? Like access null pointer in some case or some other cases which may cause segment fault?

Comment: Too high a recursion depth can report as anything or nothing - it's undefined (or maybe unspecified)  behaviour. In this case it's fairly obvious you will  overflow the call stack for any commonly-used operating system.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, is there any functional bugs in my code which may cause seg fault? Like access null pointer in some case or some other cases which may cause segment fault?

Comment: Think about how many calls to `canWinNimHelper(n-1` you need to get from 1 billion stones to just 3.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have any pointers in it, so "no". The problem is almost certainly the recursion depth.

Comment: @BoPersson, so your suspect is also recursive too high? If you can prove, it will be great, I tried gdb, does not tell too much for recursive.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, thanks. I tried gdb, but it does not tell recursive too high. Is there a way to find more info to prove recursive too high is the culprit?

Comment: As Bo Persson 's comment explains, it's obviously too high. But if you want to track it in a debugger, keep tabs on the value of the stack pointer and what it is accessing.

Comment: @NeilButterworth, thanks. Maybe you can add a reply, it will benefit other people who has the similar questions. I will mark it as answer to help search. :)